# Re-Projecting lat and long in python Geopandas but geometry unchanged

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geometry, latitude-longitude, geopandas

Here the question:

the original dataset is like this:

[image]

and I want to convert it to normal location like this kind:

[image]

I try load the original file in into geopandas and set the projections, to achieve that goal, but unsuccessful.

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point


path_Tw = r'\\Goa\shared\AEP\EMSD\IEAP\EnvData_Prediction\Predictions\Modelling_Projects\Water\Hydrology\1_Data\5_Township\TownshipGrid_Domain\PerGrid(1961-2016)_AllDomain'
path_Tw_loc = os.path.join(path_Tw, "..")                                                    


all_tws = pd.read_csv(path_Tw_loc + r'\Township_CentroidPoints.csv', sep=',',index_col=[0])         
ft = all_tws.values

point = ft[:,:2]

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(point[:,0], point[:,1])]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
celldf = GeoDataFrame(  crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

`point` stores the orginal loaded csv information:

[image]

I think the geometry will changed to pic2's kind, as I have done this conversion:

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(point[:,0], point[:,1])]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
celldf = GeoDataFrame(  crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

but actually in the final `celldf`, the geometry still unchanged:

[image]

Anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: The `crs` you specify in `GeoDataFrame( ... crs=...)` should be the original CRS (so the one of your X/Y data), not the one to which you want to convert it. The afterwards, you can do `celldf = celldf.to_crs(epsg=4326)`

Comment: @ joris no, that might not be the problem, i have checked before, print `celldf.crs` and it is {'init': 'epsg:4326'}. I also tried the code you wrote, turns out the `celldf` is still the same

Comment: @wflwo You set celldf.crs to epsg:4326, but your data are clearly not epsg:4326 (lat/long max values are 180, e.g.). When you load your dataframe all_tws, you can get its actual crs with all_tws.crs.

Comment: @wflwo I am pretty sure this is the problem .. You are loading the data from csv, so it has no CRS information, you have to know and set the correct CRS for that data yourself to start with, before you can convert it to another CRS.

Comment: @joris, yes, you are right, this is also why I am confused that the shapefile can just do the re-projection but those csv columns have troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As joris says, you need to know the source crs and the destination crs

Example with a shapefile

```
import geopandas as gpd
t = gpd.read_file("test.shp")
print t.columns
Index([u'id', u'x', u'y', u'geometry'], dtype='object')
# source crs
print t.crs
{u'lon_0': 4.367486666666666, u'ellps': u'intl', u'y_0': 5400088.438, u'no_defs': True, u'proj': u'lcc', u'x_0': 150000.013, u'units': u'm', u'lat_2': 49.8333339, u'lat_1': 51.16666723333333, u'lat_0': 90}
t.head(2)
  id        x              y                geometry 
0  a  153643.920161  121012.189193   POINT (153643.9201609589 121012.1891931929) 
1  b  154373.424542   98766.947558   POINT (154373.4245420386 98766.94755783956)
```

Now change the projection of the GeoDataframe

```
# destination crs     
t_wgs84 = t.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'}) 
t_wgs84.head(2)
  id              x              y                geometry 
0  a  153643.920161  121012.189193   POINT (4.418739274219395 50.40055770646124)  
1  b  154373.424542   98766.947558   POINT (4.428741839845799 50.20056337850551)
```

Direct example with shapely and [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) (GeoPandas use shapely for geometries and pyproj for projections) and the t.x, t.y coordinates

```
from shapely import Point
geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(t.x, t.y)]
# Change projection
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from shapely.ops import transform
project = partial(
      pyproj.transform,
      pyproj.Proj(t.crs), # source coordinate system
      pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'))  # destination coordinate system
print transform(project, geom[0])
POINT (4.418739274219395 50.40055770646124)
print transform(project, geom[1])
POINT (4.428741839845799 50.20056337850551)
POINT (4.429999995821303 50.20000000271339)
```

With the geometries of the GeoDataFrame

```
print t.geometry[0]
POINT (153643.9201609589 121012.1891931929)
print transform(project, t.geometry[0])
POINT (4.418739274219395 50.40055770646124)
...
```